# PHP variables not declaring?

Tags: php, mysqli

I found a tutorial for a mysqli and php login page to add to a website, i followed that tutorial step by step, spent at least 7 hours trying to figure out why it won't work, searching Google endlessly but nothing.

The code seems to be working but it seems two variables won't declare and it's skipping over them, I'll enter an email and password, hit log in, then ill get the notification 'Email or password are incorrect' the database is setup correctly and linked it just seems like it's one line of code and i can't figure it out.

Any input is welcome even if it's something basic, i am only learning this stuff hence the tutorial i was following, just want to know what is wrong and why.

Thanks.

Html Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html><?php session_start();?>

<html>

<head>

<title>Sign In</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

<header>

<a href="index.html"><img src="images/Header.jpg" alt="logo" /></a>

</header>


<header>
<a href="login.html"><img src="images/login.jpg" alt="login" /></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/ArcticMonkeys"><img src="images/Facebook.jpg" alt="FB" /></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/arcticmonkeys"><img src="images/Twitter.jpg" alt="Twitter" /></a>

</header>

<div class="menu">
<div align="center">
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <li class="item"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
    <li class="item"><a href="videos.html">Videos</a>
    <li class="item"><a href="discography.html">Discography</a>
    <li class="item"><a href="register.html">Register</a>

     <li class="item"><a href="#">About</a>
        <ul class="list">
            <li><a href="alex.html">Alex Turner</a></li>
            <li class="list">
                <a href="matt.html">Matt Helders</a>
                <ul class="list">
                    <a href="jamie.html">Jamie Cook</a>
                    <ul class="list">
                        <a href="nick.html">Nick O'Malley</a>
                        <ul class="list">
                            <a href="andy.html">Andy Nicholson</a>
                            <ul class="list">
                        </ul>
            </li>


</div>
</div>


<div align="center"><BR><BR><BR><BR>
<body id="body-color"> 

<div id="Sign-In"> 




</head>

<form action="login.php" method="post">

<table width="500" align="center">

<tr align="center">

<td colspan="3"><h2>User Login</h2></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td align="right"><b>Email</b></td>

<td><input type="text" name="email" required="required"/></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td align="right"><b>Password:</b></td>

<td><input type="password" name="pass" required="required"></td>

</tr>

<tr align="center">

<td colspan="3">

<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"/>


</td>

</tr>

</table>

</form>

<br><br>
<br><br>

<H3>If you do not have an account please register <a href="register.html">HERE</a><br>otherwise access is restricted to member pages<h3>

</div> 

</body> 

</html>
```

Here's the php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html><?php session_start();?>
//Forgot this line when first posting //
<?php

// establishing the MySQLi connection



$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","info");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())

{

echo "MySQLi Connection was not established: " . mysqli_connect_error();

}

// checking the user

if(isset($_POST['login'])){

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);

$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass']);

$sel_user = ("select * from users where user_email='$email' AND user_pass='$pass'");  
//This is where i think my problem is,  $email and $pass are highlighted grey
instead of how normally declared variables would look. //

$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $sel_user);

$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);

if($check_user>0){

$_SESSION['user_email']=$email;

echo "<script>window.open('home.php','_self')</script>";

}

else {

echo "<script>alert('Email or password is not correct, try again!')</script>";

}

}

?>
```

Here is a link to screenshots they might give more clarity [http://imgur.com/bX6HSmD,qFvyTGK,xEEiBi6,yAEvqAR,OdgRYFZ,U48OWkh]

Comment: "but it seems two variables won't declare and it's skipping over them" — Have you tried `echo`ing out your complete query to see if that is the case?

Comment: **Danger**: "Not hashing at all" is [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php); you need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: how do we know you didn't make any mistakes in the HTML form? and how do we know if this line isn't really uncommented `instead of how normally declared variables would look. //` - Check for errors.

Comment: Voted to close as unclear till we see and know what the full picture is.

Comment: @Quentin I can't get over how all the answers (so far) aren't paying attention to code flow. I voted to close as unclear, as stated above.

Comment: I'll edit and post the code now and include photos.

Comment: @RyanOBhaoil — Screenshots of your IDE's syntax highlighting aren't very useful.  See the first comment I made and test your assumptions. See Fred's comments and use the Net tab of the developer tools in your browser to see what HTTP request you are actually making (is it POST? does it have the data you want in it?)

Comment: Unrelated to the problem at hand, you can't output HTTP headers (which `session_start()` will try to do) after you've started the document (which outputting `<!DOCTYPE...` will do).

Comment: @Quentin I'd say that having `session_start();` below the doc declaration would hinder OP's code. Ryan, you're outputting before header, that's why your code is failing, and check your table's column types and lengths.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- — It would, but not enough to make the `if` statement go down the wrong branch.

Comment: For one thing, login.html or index.html contains PHP code, can't do that unless you've instructed Apache to treat those as PHP. also make sure no whitespace is involved.

Comment: At the moment, my best guess is that the email address and password being entered aren't actually in the database table.

Comment: question is now; where is this code being executed from, your own PC or a hosted site? If your own, is everything installed and properly configured? did you create the right database and table? are the column types correct and the right lengths? does data exist? At this point, this question makes it even harder, if not impossible to answer. Echo/var_dump and again, check for errors.

Comment: email and pass are in the database [http://imgur.com/p8hNzmP] i have easyphp installed and running off a usb, hosted offline, i don't have much intention of putting it online just want to get better at coding. when running the network tool through firefox it's saying it is POST [http://imgur.com/LCAtzBR]

Comment: You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security.

Comment: is it necessary tho it the website won't be hosted online?

Comment: You said "*just want to get better at coding*", so yes. You should also learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: oh i well i just meant for this site here, didn't mean in general, i've looke at some stuff on password protection and how to protect your site from sql injection i just didn't think this site would need it. once i have this basic site up and running and understand everything about it ill start to make it more advanced.

Comment: Ah....ok. I am one of those "if you aren't going to do it right the first time when are you going to find the time to do it over?" guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your screenshot's password column is `user_password` but your column is `user_pass` in your query.

```
AND user_pass='$pass'
    ^^^^^^^^^
```

**Having checked for errors would have signaled that**, unknown column.

As I mentioned in comments to add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`.

[image]

---

**Edit:**

It has been mentioned but I am including this here, should some of those comments get deleted in regards to password storage and prepared statements.

Since you appear to be new at this, it's good to start learning about using proper hashing and safe queries.

Storing passwords in plain text isn't safe, not for online use anyway or should anyone hack into your own PC; it is highly discouraged.

I recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Plus, in regards to SQL injection,  [**use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Comment: that fixed everything, working perfectly now. will remember to add that in next time, thank you so much! greatly appreciated!

Comment: @RyanOBhaoil You're welcome Ryan. Lordie, I'm glad this one got resolved, *cheers*

Comment: Two days trying to figure it out and it was something so simple haha! life saver

Comment: @RyanOBhaoil I know the feeling. I'm working on something right now, and I'm 3 days into; and counting. Looking for the dimmest of light to start appearing at the end of the tunnel.

Comment: Good luck, im sure you'll find it, cheers for the input on this again!

Comment: @RyanOBhaoil Thank you Ryan, I'll get there. You're very much welcome. In addition, I made an edit to my answer, just in case someone deletes their comments about passwords and prepared statements. It does happen, either deleted by them or moderators. *Cheers, and enjoy coding*

Answer (score -1):

use `if(session_id() == "")
     {session_start();}` at the top of the page, anything before

Comment: Try to change your code
 

       $sel_user = ("select * from users where user_email='$email' AND user_pass='$pass'"); 

by 

 echo   $sel_user = "select * from users where user_email='$email' AND user_pass='$pass'";  
 
And test your select in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: I have <!DOCTYPE html><?php session_start();?> at the top of the page, i replaced the code with yours and it's still the same, just going straight to the last echo 'wrong email or password' it still looks like $email and $pass aren't properly declared as well [http://imgur.com/kmVKrga]

Answer (score -1):

You need to start a session in all your PHP Scripts which use sessions. Use: `session_start();`before calling `$_SESSION` and then set the `$_SESSION` with the desired value.

Comment: I have that in it, missed it when i was c&p was at the very top, sorry problem is fixed now in the original post.

Comment: `$_SESSION` isn't being touched. The `if` branch with it is isn't touched.

Comment: Is echo "<script>window.open('home.php','_self')</script>"; executing at least?

Comment: @ProtectedVoid — Of course it isn't. The question says that `echo "<script>alert('Email or password is not correct, try again!')</script>";` is executing.